# MySQL: Where clause in Trigger, Column which is not null = column or is null

Tags: mysql

I need help with a where clause to return values where co1 which is not null = col2 or is null.

```
id | col1 | col2 | result
1  |   a  |      |  True
2  |   b  |   b  |  True
3  |      |   c  |  False
4  |      |      |  False
```

id1 evaluates to true because col1 is not null and col2 is null. id2 evaluates to true because col1 = col2. id3 evaluates to false because col1 is null. id4 evaluates to false because col1 is still null.

This Fiddle may help explain more of what I’m trying to accomplish if the above is unclear.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=287c91f43c17e4b48925412b8821cec5

Comment: no absolutely not, first try a SELECT that gets you one result, you hgave two tables and in your post only one, you compare tab2 and tab1 and the rules are not clear

Comment: @John_Scully . . . Your question is rather unclear.  The explanation and sample data do not match.

Comment: Sorry it was unclear. I’m new to MySQL and even asking it the way I did took time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`null` is not a value, it is the lack thereof, and always returns null when compared using the `=` operator. So if `col1 = col2`, it means that they are both not `null`, and are equal. In short, you could query this with two simple conditions with an `or` logical operator:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   mytable
WHERE  col1 = col2 OR (col1 IS NOT NULL AND col2 IS NULL)
```

Comment: null = null is neither true or false, I guess

Comment: @shikida `null = null` is `null`. I meant "it never returns true`", but indeed had a wrong statement there. Edited and fixed, thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 0):

> I need help with a where clause to return values where co1 which is not null = col2 or is null.

This is describing:

```
where col1 = col2 or col1 is null
```

However, you might want a `NULL`-safe comparison.  That would treat `NULL = NULL`.  If so, MySQL offers one:

```
where col1 <=> col2
```

If you are trying to calculate the `result` column, that would most succinctly be expressed as:

```
where col1 = coalesce(col2, col1)
```

I would describe this as "col1 = col2 or col2 is null and col1 is not null".

Comment: actually, the question is not exactly consistent. the example shows that when col1 is null, the result is false

Answer (score 0):

I think you are searching for such a update Query

> ```
> CREATE TRIGGER trigger_01
>     AFTER UPDATE
>     ON Tab2
>     FOR EACH ROW
>     BEGIN
>     UPDATE Tab3
>     SET results  = ( SELECT results FROM Tab1 
>  where IF(NEW.user_col1 is not NULL OR NEW.user_col1 = '',IF( Tab1.col1 = NEW.user_col1, 1,0),1)
>  and IF(NEW.user_col2 is not NULL OR NEW.user_col2 = '',IF( Tab1.col2 = NEW.user_col2, 1,0),1)
>  and IF(NEW.user_col3 is not NULL OR NEW.user_col3 = '',IF( Tab1.col3 = NEW.user_col3, 1,0),1)
>  AND IF(NEW.user_col4 is not NULL OR NEW.user_col4 = '',IF( Tab1.col4= NEW.user_col4, 1,0),1)
>     ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1);
>     end;
> ```

> ```
> UPDATE Tab2
> Set user_col1 = 'a'
> Where user_id = 1;
>
> UPDATE Tab2
> Set user_col2 = ''
> Where user_id = 1;
>
> UPDATE Tab2
> Set user_col3 = ''
> Where user_id = 1;
>
> UPDATE Tab2
> Set user_col4 = 'd'
> Where user_id = 1;
>
> SELECT * FROM Tab2 where user_id =1;
> SELECT * FROM Tab3 where user_id = 1;
> ```
>
> ```
> user_id | user_col1 | user_col2 | user_col3 | user_col4
> ------: | :-------- | :-------- | :-------- | :--------
>       1 | a         |           |           | d        
>
> user_id | results
> ------: | :------
>       1 | Audi
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4f60856322ba1bd4e8d0f3a3aa27b0c2)*